# what is the difference between configuration type and build type in cmake

Tags: cmake

What is the difference between `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES` and `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`?

The document claims they are dinstinguished by `multi-config` or `single-config`, what does it mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CMake is a generator of a build system (yeah, it doesn't build anything by itself).

Some generators are *single-configuration* (e.g., *Unix Makefiles* or *Ninja*). This means that you specify a building type (via `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=XXX`) and `cmake --build .` will build only this type (e.g. `Debug`, `Release`, ...) from the generated build directory.

The others are *multi-config* generators (e.g., *Visual Studio NN YYYY* or *Ninja Multi-Config*) -- i.e., you provide a set of configurations (via `-DCMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES=Debug;Release`) and the generated build system can build any (or all) of the list out of the single build directory (via `cmake --build . --config <name>`).

So, generally, *single-configuration* generators (**not all** of them) check the `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` variable for the desired configuration type. Whereas the *multi-configuration* generators look for the list of desired configurations in the `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES`.

Except for these (two) variables a generator may check some other variables in order to "tune" smth. Better to read the documentation of the [particular generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) for the details.

Comment: Thanks for this clear answer. One possible question remains: What is the difference between `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES` and `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`?

Comment: @Xudong I've updated the answer... However, your question sounds like _what is the difference between variable `FOO` and `BAR`_ ;) -- obviously, it's a name, their values, and the context they are used... some other code use `FOO`, the other may use `BAR` ;)

Comment: Yes, thanks for this update! Now I understand the fact, that `single-config` generator choose `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` for their behaviors to be determined.